# How to match when letters aren't the same?

Tags: nsregularexpression

Suppose I want to match four-letter words whose first and last letters are *not* the same. What is a regex that will do this?

For example, I tried this:
^(.)..[^\1]$
but got no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookahead solves your problem.

`/^(.)..(?!\1).$/`

https://regex101.com/r/MvqXdE/1